# How to make a property obligatory in a React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

Is there any best practice to make a property obligatory in a React Component?

Also is there anyway to set the properties to not nullable, so it won't be `null` or `undefined`?

Comment: You can just null check the property in the constructor and throw an `Error` if needed.

Answer (score 5):

React has some built-in typechecking abilities, by using the `prop-types` package ([read more](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html))

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const myProp = this.props.myProp;
    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  myProp: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

Keep in mind, that this type checking is only done in development mode.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on desirable behaviour.

A common way is to use React prop types, as other answers already mention. They result in a *warning* (although outputted as console error) in development mode, while they are no-op in production.

There is no existing non-nullable type, so it can be custom prop type function:

```
const nullablePropType = (props, propName, componentName)  => {
  if (props[propName] == null)
    return new Error('Prop `' + propName + '` is nullable in `' + componentName + '`.');
};

const Foo = props => ...;
Foo.propTypes = { bar: nullablePropType };
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are obligatory, you can check properties at `constructor` or `componentDidMount` or `getDerivedStateFromProps` [component lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle) and handle them there.

Or use [default props](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#defaultprops) that auto set values for `undefined` props (`null` treated as a value)